# How to compare environment variable that contains multiple values to response body json

Tags: javascript, json, function, environment-variables, postman

I have an environment variable that I use within a body of a PATCH, I want to ensure that this matches the one within the response body of the same PATCH.

The environment variable and response body are structured exactly the same:

```
"compliance":{
        "documents": true,
        "shareInfo": true,
        "applicationUnderstood": true,
        "authoriseCheck": true,
        "drivingLicenceType": "EU"
    }
```

I've tried the following but it errored with 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'documents' of undefined'

```
pm.test("Assert ComplianceDetails", function () {
    var complianceData = (pm.environment.get("Compliance"))
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.documents).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.documents)
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.shareInfo).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.shareInfo)
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.applicationUnderstood).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.applicationUnderstood)
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.authoriseCheck).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.authoriseCheck)
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.drivingLicenceType).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.drivingLicenceType)
});
```

I've managed to get this to work using .split(' ') but don't want to make my tests brittle if something is to change in the future. Is there a way of using something like the above to get this to work? I don't really want to separate out the environment variable any further either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have set postman varaible through script as :

```
pm.environment.set("Compliance",{"compliance":{
        "documents": true,
        "shareInfo": true,
        "applicationUnderstood": true,
        "authoriseCheck": true,
        "drivingLicenceType": "EU"
    }})
```

Then it will be stored as javascript object and your code works as it is:

```
    var complianceData = (pm.environment.get("Compliance"))
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.documents).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.documents)
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.shareInfo).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.shareInfo)
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.applicationUnderstood).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.applicationUnderstood)
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.authoriseCheck).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.authoriseCheck)
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.drivingLicenceType).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.drivingLicenceType)
```

**Else if you have copy and pasted the content to environment variable, then it is stored as string , you have to parse it first:**

```
var complianceData = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("Compliance"))
pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.documents).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.documents)
pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.shareInfo).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.shareInfo)
pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.applicationUnderstood).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.applicationUnderstood)
pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.authoriseCheck).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.authoriseCheck)
pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.drivingLicenceType).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.drivingLicenceType)
```

### Comment

below object is not a valid javascript object , you have to enclose it with curly bracket:

**Invalid:**

```
"compliance":{
        "documents": true,
        "shareInfo": true,
        "applicationUnderstood": true,
        "authoriseCheck": true,
        "drivingLicenceType": "EU"
    }
```

**valid:**

```
{
    "compliance":{
            "documents": true,
            "shareInfo": true,
            "applicationUnderstood": true,
            "authoriseCheck": true,
            "drivingLicenceType": "EU"
        }
}
```

if you don't want to make to store it in that format, then in script you can do:

```
  var complianceData = "{"+(pm.environment.get("Compliance"))+"}"
  // or `{${pm.environment.get("Compliance")}}`
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when using JSON.parse I now getting the following error:  JSONError: Unexpected token ':' at 1:13 "compliance":{ ^

I think this is because ':' isn't recongised as valid JSON? Is there a way of using JSON.parse if your string contains invalid json values?

Comment: you have to enclose complieanse also with {} like `{"complaince":{restofcode}{`

Comment: The body of the patch looks like this:
`{
    "sendForProcessing": true,
    {{PersonalInformation}}
    {{ContactInformation}}
   {{Compliance}}
}`
When adding the {} to the Compliance variable as you suggested I get an error 400 as it invalidates the PATCH. I think this is because it's already been enclosed within the PATCH body, however even though it's enclosed within the body of the request I still get the JSONError.

Comment: I've just managed to get this to work with the following that you suggested.

`pm.test("Assert ComplianceDetails", function () {
    var complianceData = JSON.parse(`{${pm.environment.get("Compliance")}}`)
    pm.expect(jsonData.compliance.documents).to.eql(complianceData.compliance.documents)
});`

Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated